# input text field padding

Tags: text, alignment, field, padding

i have this simple code - one text field and one image (height of image is 30px)

the code is:

```
<input type="text" style="height:30px;" />
<input type="image" src="images/download_button.png" />
```

and result is two element with height 30px that are not aligned. The text field is down relative to image - like padding??? Do you know, why the element is not aligned???

screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
           Assuming your form id is "myform"

            #myform input{

            vertical-align:middle;

        }

       will do the trick.
if you are not using form:Try

<input type="text" style="height:30px;vertical-align:middle;" />
<input type="image" style="height:30px;vertical-align:middle;" src="images/download_button.png" />
```

Comment: @KirilSpasov Not much point in a text input without a form to send it back to the server. But that's a separate issue.

Comment: then just add it to your form fields.

Comment: <input type="text" style="height:30px;vertical-align:middle;" />
<input type="image" style="height:30px;vertical-align:middle;" src="images/download_button.png" />

Comment: add form... result are same... :(((((((

Comment: add form. give your form an id(eg."myform").Now add css as follows:#myform input{vertical-align:middle;}  I checked and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Both answers work, but I'm guessing from the nature of the question you're not much of a stickler for understanding why. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing padding and margin:

```
<input type="text" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;height:30px;" />
<input type="image" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;" src="images/download_button.png" />
```

Remember that the text input box is likely to add 2 pixels either side of the block for its border. You could remove the border all together with `border:0;`.

Also, double check any contradicting CSS rules elsewhere in your markup.

**EDIT:**

It's to do with the behaviour of the inputs in regards to floating. Add `float:left;` to both style to see what I mean. They don't know how to behave next to each other until you specify that you want them to appear on the same line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly, that you suggest doesn't work! Check yor code....

Comment: I don't have your download_button.png, so I can't really test it fully. This is just a guess. Are you saying that the HTML breaks or are you saying that setting margin, padding and border to 0 does not solve your problem? I would do the same for the image, also.

Comment: just take any image with 30px height, or give me email to send it.
Yess, I try that you suggest, but it doesn't work... I also was wander from result, but this is fact... TEST IT!!

Comment: I was being lazy :-) I've had another stab, see my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS "top" properties to increase the buttons distance from the top:

```
<style> 
  [selector for image] {top: 20px;}
</style>`
```